# Why the code is not reached?

Tags: javascript, moodle

I have 2 webpages where the code works on one page but on the other page it won't work. The code is supposed to open a new window with the submitted file to display the submitted file. For some reason it won't do it on the page that fails.

The code that is taken from moodle is:

```
function openDV(dvtype, submission_id, coursemoduleid) {
        alert('i opendv');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../../plagiarism/turnitin/ajax.php",
            dataType: "html",
            data: {action: dvtype, submission: submission_id, cmid: coursemoduleid},

            success: function(data) {
                alert('i success');
                $("."+dvtype+"_form_"+submission_id).html(data);
                alert('i success 2: '+"."+dvtype+"_form_"+submission_id);
                $("."+dvtype+"_form_"+submission_id).children("form").on("submit", function(event) {
                    alert('debug 2');
                    dvWindow = window.open('', 'dv_'+submission_id);
                    dvWindow.document.write('<frameset><frame id="dvWindow" name="dvWindow"></frame></frameset>');
                    dvWindow.document.close();
                    $(dvWindow).bind('beforeunload', function() {
                        refreshScores(submission_id, coursemoduleid);
                    });
                });
                alert('i success 3');
                $("."+dvtype+"_form_"+submission_id).children("form").submit();
                $("."+dvtype+"_form_"+submission_id).html("");
            },
            error: function() {
                alert('error!');
            }

    });
    }
```

On the failing page, the code that is `alert('debug 2');` is not reached. Why?

Comment: `$("."+dvtype+"_form_"+submission_id).children("form").on("submit",` only attaches an event handler, but does not invoke it. PS: that's an awful piece of code, make sure you don't leave traces that it was you who wrote it.

Comment: @zerkms Ok but why does it work on other pages? It also works locally but not on the reference server. I thought there should be some difference, but the line is invoked on the other page where the code is used.

Comment: I'm not sure what "work" means in this case: `.on()` only attaches a handler and never invokes it. Just by definition.

Comment: And a general advice: take debugger and debug it.

Comment: @zerkms "work" means that it opens a popup window which is does on 3 of 4 pages. On the fourth page it doesn't reach the inside of the function. I tried debugging it with firebug and got no information. Can you please let me know what the error could be?

Comment: Error code for what? This code is syntactically correct. The biggest problem here is that for as trivial task as just sending one ajax request and handling one form submission this code is TOO MUCH tangled (not to say it's spaghetti). If you want to find out the issue the best way to do that is to rewrite it clearly from the scratch and then to explain how you expect it to work (at the moment it does not make much sense and we have no idea what your expectations about this code are)

Comment: The code is taken from Moodle. It's from the turnitin module. I did not write the code, it's included with the turntnin plugin for Moodle. It works localy and is used for plagiarism control as a Moodle function. When deployed to the reference server it won't work on one of the pages. I can't understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not part of the Moodle core code, so I'm guessing its a download of this plugin?

https://moodle.org/plugins/view/plagiarism_turnitin

There are 2 versions though, the old one is at https://github.com/danmarsden/moodle-plagiarism_turnitin

The latest one is at https://github.com/jmcgettrick/moodle-plagiarism_turnitin

I had a very quick look and couldn't see the ajax code.

Where did you download the code from? Also what version of Moodle are you using? Maybe check you are using the latest version of the plugin for your version of Moodle.

UPDATE: The Moodle page above says that the turnitin module needs to be installed too. Is this installed on the destination server?

https://moodle.org/plugins/view/mod_turnitintooltwo

UPDATE 2: Ah yes, the ajax code is in turnitintooltwo

https://github.com/jmcgettrick/moodle-mod_turnitintooltwo/blob/master/jquery/turnitintooltwo.js

It looks like the code your are using is out of date.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try with the latest version.